# How do I get the position of an element in listview when I am dragging an element on top of it?

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop, position, coordinates

I started dragging an item from one listView to another. When I am dragging the element on top of the target listView, I need to get the position of the element that is currently under my dragged element. That way I somehow need to find the position of the element, over which my dragged element was dropped, to place this dragged element in the position it was dropped.